# ASP Dropdown on Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a Drop Down using Aspx, which will list all the items contained in a data source but it will have an additional default value of "selected".

In the aspx file, I have:

```
<aspx:DropDownList
    ID="ddl1"
    runat="server"/>
```

In my aspx.cs file, I have a page_load, which contains:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ddl1.DataSource = LocationofData;
  ddl1.DataBind();
}
```

And let's assume that LocationofData will populate the values "a,b,c,etc...". I want the default value to be "--selected--"

How should I approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
      ddl1.DataSource = LocationofData;
      ddl1.DataBind();

      //first item in the list
      ddl1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select--",""));
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and I believe you got the order backwards. It should be: 
    new ListItem("--Select--",""); 

Thanks for the reply though. Also, why does it occur after the DataBind()? As in why should I not bind the new item?

Comment: Binding data to dropdownlist refreshes it with the new data. There is a `AppendDataBoundItems` property of dropdownlist that you can use to avoid that but I don't like it. It always give problem. After binding, then insert to position 0, first item location.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code

```
ddl1.Items.Add("--selected--"); //After your bind
```

So :

```
ddl1.DataSource = LocationofData;
ddl1.DataBind();
ddl1.Items.Add("--selected--"); //After your bind
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s6873c.aspx

You can also use `Insert method`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffx2x2y2.aspx

Comment: Why should the item add be after the bind?

Comment: @Rhs in order to print in the top of your control, is known practise

Answer (score 0):

I think best practice is to use ondatabound which calls the BaseDataBoundControl.DataBound event:
ASP.NET Control:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl1"
  ondatabound="MyListDataBound"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void MyListDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddl1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Select -", ""));
}
```